# Chef node - check if recipe will run on it, looking inside roles as well

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I want to find out if a specific recipe will be run on a node from inside a different recipe. I can node.recipe?(recipe_name) method, however some of my recipies are managed by roles and recipe? does not seem to look into the roles run list.

Is there an easy way to find out if my recipie[redis] is going to be run on the current node?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for the `recipes` method.  Note the trailing `s`!  So:

```
node.recipes.include?(recipe_name)
```

Also note that there is a similar pair of methods for role inspection.  Those are `role` and `roles`.  For both roles and recipes, the singular form is for those *directly* assigned and the plural for the fully resolved set.

Comment: The best documentation on this I can find is the chef ticket [CHEF-1587](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-1587) which points at a chef source file [node.rb](https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/node.rb), which seems to contradict your pluralization, no? Or am I missing a ruby-ism?

Comment: It's not a contradiction, but rather an API with multiple access points for the same data.  I presume you're referring to the `recipe?` method, which appears to also be a valid choice - preferable in fact.  The difference is that `recipes` and `roles` are attributes that are auto-expanded: https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/node.rb#L339, and chef allows you to query attributes via method calls.

Comment: Oh, hmm, I did read that line before but didn't understand how it works. Makes more sense with your explanation. Thanks! (And yes, I was talking about the `recipe?` definition on line 246.)