# How to check if recipe is included/applied with Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I have a wrapper cookbook that includes `postgresql::server`. In another cookbook I want to check if that recipe is applied. Using `node.recipe? 'postgresql::server'` I cannot test for that.

How can I do this with Chef?

Comment: Does Ohai tell you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chef node - check if recipe will run on it, looking inside roles as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330553/chef-node-check-if-recipe-will-run-on-it-looking-inside-roles-as-well)

Answer (score 4):

Try `node['recipes'].include?  'postgresql::server'`

For what it worth, according to [the code](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/node.rb#L281-L283) , your `node.recipe?` should work with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness:
In principle `node.recipe?` is the right way to go.

But in the *compile phase* of your chef run, `node['recipes']` will initially only contain the recipes in your explicitly defined run list.
It will be completed during the compilation phase with every `include_recipe` that occurs.

Therefore:
If your `node.recipe? 'postgresql::server'` is evaluated before a `include_recipe 'postgresql::server'` in the order of compilation, it will return `false`.

Answer (score -1):

From here: https://docs.chef.io/run_lists.html

```
knife status --run-list

knife status "role:web" --run-list
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: OP is looking for a test in a recipe, not from knife.